# Two FileNotFoundException-s when trying to download

Tags: php, laravel, exception, download

So i'm using Laravel for a while. I wrote this:

```
public function downloadUserFile(){
        $result = $_POST['filename'];
        $entry = File::where('filename', '=', $result)->firstOrFail();
        $file = Storage::disk()->get(storage_path($entry->filePath));
        $headers = array('Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="'.basename($entry->filePath).'"', 'Content-Type' => $entry->mimetype );
        return (new Response($file, 200))->header($headers);
}
```

With the hope that I can download a selected file. Well I get two exceptions in FilesystemAdapter.php line 58 and in Filesystem.php line 381: File not found at path: C:\xampp\htdocs\bluedrive\drive\storage\uploads\1\SHTURCITE - Ti I Az.mp3 ----  This file is in the directory and i can't understand why laravel can't find it.